# How to save result in separate column in excel using shell script

Tags: excel, bash, shell, awk

I am saving the executed output in the excel sheet, the results will show in the new row like below

I do have the request like this,

```
db.cassandra.contactPoints     10.11.12.13
db.cassandra.port                8080
server.host                10.10.10.10:9443
server2.host             10.12.12.12:9001
sftp.host             abcdiefgh.unix.hes2000.org
sftp.port                     22


Expected output

filename                   hostname          Port
db.cassandra.contactPoints  10.11.12.13        8080
server.host                 10.10.10.10        9443
server2.host                10.12.12.12        9001
sftp.host          abcdiefgh.unix.hes2000.org   22
```

I have used below script

```
grep -P '((?<=[^0-9.]|^)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\.([0-9]{0,3})){3}(?=[^0-9.]|$)|(http|ftp|https|ftps|sftp)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?|\.port|\.host|contact-points|\.uri)' $filename | awk 'BEGIN {print "Column_A\tColumn_B"}NR%2 {if(next = "%port%"){printf "%s \t",$0;next;}}1' | grep '^[^#]' | awk '{split($0,a,"="); print a[1],","a[2]}'
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to add 3 simple things. 1- sample of input,2- sample of output and 3rd- efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem. So please edit your question. Also add sample in form of text with CODE TAGS in your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  print "Filename hostname port"
}
/:[0-9]+/{
  sub(/:/,"\t")
  print;
  next
}
NF==2{
  if($NF~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ || $NF~/[a-zA-Z]+\..*\.[a-zA-Z]+$/){
    val=$0
  }
  else{
    if(val){
      print val,$NF
      val=""
    }
  }
}
' Input_file | column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code here.

```
awk '                                                                             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                                                            ##Starting BEGIN section of this program here.
  print "Filename hostname port"                                                  ##Printing header for output here.
}
/:[0-9]+/{                                                                        ##Checking condition if line has colon digits then do following.
  sub(/:/,"\t")                                                                   ##Substitute colon with TAB here in line.
  print;                                                                          ##Printing the current line here.
  next                                                                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
NF==2{                                                                            ##Checking condition if number of fields in a Line are 2 then do following.
  if($NF~/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/ || $NF~/[a-zA-Z]+\..*\.[a-zA-Z]+$/){    ##If a line is in ip format or domain format then do following.
    val=$0                                                                        ##Creating variable val which has current line value in it.
  }
  else{                                                                           ##Mentioning else here.
    if(val){                                                                      ##Checking condition if variable val is NOT NULL then do following.
      print val,$NF                                                               ##Printing variable val and last field of line here.
      val=""                                                                      ##Nullifying variable val here.
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file | column -t                                                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here and passing whole output to column command.
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Ravinder, It's not printing any values,

Comment: @KalpanaPinninty, for given samples it's working fine for me, could you please check if you have if you have control characters by doing `cat -v Input_file` and lemme know then?? If you see any carriage returns or control m characters

Comment: I need to do add your script in my script? i am not getting the output, can you please guide me

Comment: @KalpanaPinninty, IMHO first you should run my script alone and see if its working. Please see my previous comment if you have if you have control characters by doing cat -v Input_file and lemme know then??